# Manage multiple browser tabs in signalr

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sockets, signalr

I am developing a chat application like facebook in `MVC 4`.

I am connecting to hub like following

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

$.connection.transports.longPolling.supportsKeepAlive = function () {
    return false;
}
$.connection.hub.qs = "UserID=" + $('#hdfLoggedInUserID').val();
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //...
});
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

And my `hub` class is like following

```
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var userID = Context.QueryString["UserID"];
        if (userID != null)
        {
            //set user online in database and save connection_id
            RefreshOnlineUsers(uId);
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var userID = Context.QueryString["UserID"];
        if (userID != null)
        {
            //set user offline in database
            RefreshOnlineUsers(uId);
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
```

It's working fine when I am working with only one browser tab.

`OnConnected` calls when browser tab open and `OnDisconnected` calls when browser tab closed. 
So according to this when I open one tab then `OnConnected` calls and user's status(online) and `connection_id` update in database.

After that I open my application in new tab of same browser then `OnConnected` method calls again and user's new `connection_id` and status(online) update in database.

After that when I close new browser tab then `OnDiconnected` calls and user's status changes to offline in database. But user is still online in previous browser tab.

Due to this issue this user is offline according to database but it's online.

I am already done lot of R&D about it but can't find any proper solution.

**Q : How can I resolve this multiple browser tab issue?**

Thanks.

Comment: You are only tracking the user whereas you need to track the connectionId also. When the user has no active connectionIds then they are offline etc

Comment: Thanks @thab this will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [thab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292533/thab).

You said :

> You are only tracking the user whereas you need to track the connectionId also. When the user has no active connectionIds then they are offline etc

This is a great idea and I implemented this. This works great.
I am tracking `connectionId` . When the user has no active connectionIds then they will be offline other wise they will be online.

Comment: FYI I've usuaully done this using a HubPipeline - to allow reuse in any new site etc. I don't have sample code on hand though...

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have the resolution code to help me? Thank you

Comment: @LeonanMilani You can see this for reference https://github.com/stackmanoj/chatapp/blob/master/ChatApp/Common/ChatHub.cs